# Some Tailwind CSS classes using numbers no longer work

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When I've started working on my project, which is basic HTML with Tailwind CSS installed, everything worked fine. I could use all values in classes containing numbers, for example `text-2xl`, `text-8xl`, `text-9xl` and `ml-2`, `mt-6` etc.

But something went wrong and now most of these values won't work. I can't use `text-2xl/4xl/5xl/6xl/8xl/9xl`, but `text-3xl/7xl` works fine, like it used to when I started working on the project. Same with margins. For example `ml-1/2/3/4` wont work, but `ml-5` works like it used to.

**HTML:**

```html
<body class="h-screen w-screen overflow-x-clip scroll-smooth">
    <div class="h-screen w-screen flex justify-center bg-gradient-to-bl from-sky-300 to-sky-500">
        <div class="h-full w-full grid xl:grid-cols-2 items-center">

            <div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-center text-white font-slab">
                <h1 class="text-7xl ml-5">Szia!</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
        <img class="absolute w-1/4 md:w-1/12 xl:w-[4%] left-auto right-auto bottom-[5%] animate-bounce"
            src="../src/scroll.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    fontFamily: {
      'oswald': ['"Oswald"', 'sans-serif'],
      'slab': ['"Roboto Slab"', 'serif'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong or what caused this to happen.

I deleted most of the classes which included custom values, like `xl:w-[4%]`, because I though maybe that's what was causing the problem, but as far as I noticed, nothing changed.

I also tried searching for the classes in the web inspector tab, but they aren't being applied at all.

**Edit**: Deleting Just-In-Time from the config file, then `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`  on my folder solved the issue.

Comment: I tried your code out on the [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) and it seemed to have been working. Maybe try restarting your dev environment? I wonder if it also has something to do with Just-In-Time Mode. The docs mention having [a `purge` option](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode) configured in your config file.

Comment: @RicoHancock Thanks! I've tried these out, but sadly, none of them worked for me. I decided to just completely remove just in time mode anyway. Now that I think about it this is the first time this problem happened, and also the first time i used jit in tailwinds.

Comment: Huh, I wonder what could be going on. I've personally never used jit, but I love tailwind. Have you tried opening it up in an incognito window?

Comment: Okay after some intense 15 minutes of trial and error, i figured out the solution. Throw jit out of the window, then make tailwind watch my folder again in cmd. 
(npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch)
This fixed the problem. Thanks for leading me to it

Comment: Glad you got it! 

Answer (score 0):

May be `jit` is causing the problem try deleting the jit file from the config

And try watching again using

```
 npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```